# Show that the Mod 2 Linking Number is well defined.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

If $X$ and $Y$ are compact, boundaryless smooth manifolds, $f\colon X \to \mathbb R^n$ and $g\colon Y \to \mathbb R^n$ with $f(X) \cap g(Y) = \emptyset$, and with $\dim (X) +\dim (Y) =n-1$.  Define the $$L_2(f,g)=\deg_2(u_{f,g}) \text{ mod }2$$ where $u_{f,g}(x,y)=\dfrac{f(x)-g(x)}{|f(x)-g(x)|}$.

Show that $L_2(f,g)$ is well defined.

I could use some help starting this one. Just a direction to head. Thanks!

Comment: Well-defined up to ambient isotopy of the manifolds?

Comment: It looks well defined already to me. Do you mean is it well defined with respect to the linking of the manifolds $X$ and $Y$? (that is, invariant under ambient isotopy)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to show that u (as defined) satisfies the hypothesis for mod-2 degree. I might be making this harder than it is. Thanks!